# Create delimited column with all dates between dates in two other columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe showing product IDs, by retailer, with the dates each product was made available for sale and when the sale was closed.

So:

```
Retailer   Product   Active        Closed
123        A1        2014-01-01    2014-07-28  
135        A1        2014-03-05    2015-06-02
135        A2        2014-02-28    2014-03-25
```

I would like to create a table telling me every single day that each product was for sale at each retailer, either in wide or long format.

So, either:

```
Retailer   Product   Active        Closed       ForSale
123        A1        2014-01-01    2014-07-28   2014-01-01; 2014-01-02; etc 
135        A1        2014-03-05    2015-06-02   2014-03-05; 2014-03-06; etc
135        A2        2014-02-28    2014-03-25   2014-02-28; 2014-03-01; etc
```

(Obviously without the etc...listing every single date)

Or:

```
Retailer    Product    ForSale
123         A1         2014-01-01
123         A1         2014-01-02
123         A1         2014-01-03
```

...all the way until all is listed.

I have tried to use seq, like so:

```
myData$ForSale <- seq(as.Date(myData$Active), as.Date(myData$Closed), by = "days")
```

but it tells me that 'from' must be length of 1, which I don't really follow.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

FYI, str(data):

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  239440 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ iGame    : int  833 833 833 833 833 833 833 833 892 892 ...
 $ Pack     : int  180899 183796 188712 188716 178789 178792 178800 186807 14589 14639 ...
 $ ToUKey   : int  1002 1002 1002 1002 1002 1002 1002 1002 1002 1002 ...
 $ Settled  : Date, format: "2011-07-26" "2011-07-26" "2011-07-26" "2011-07-26" ...
 $ Received1: chr  "" "" "2011-07-06" "2011-07-06" ...
 $ Active   : Date, format: "2011-07-10" "2011-07-07" "2011-07-12" "2011-07-13" ...
 $ Received2: chr  "" "" "2011-07-06" "2011-07-06" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `data.table`.  The below code will get the results in the "long" format.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ ,list(ForSale=seq(Active, Closed, by='1 day')), 
                                by=list(Product, Retailer)]
```

Or you can create a `list` column "ForSale"

```
setDT(df)[ ,list(ForSale=list(seq(Active, Closed, by='1 day'))),
                              by=list(Product, Retailer)]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Retailer = c(123L, 135L, 135L), Product = c("A1", 
 "A1", "A2"), Active = structure(c(16071, 16134, 16129), class = "Date"), 
Closed = structure(c(16279, 16588, 16154), class = "Date")), 
.Names = c("Retailer", "Product", "Active", "Closed"), row.names = c(NA, -3L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I get "Error in del/by: non-numeric argument to binary operator" off the first call.

Comment: @datahappy Could you show the `str(yourdataset)`.  Here, the `Active` and `Closed` are both `Date` class and I am using `data.table_1.9.5`

Comment: I am actually running an R module in a program called Alteryx...I'll see about exporting into actual R so I can get the str(data) output.

Comment: @datahappy Please do check this in R console.

Comment: Also, I checked the classes for Active and Closed to make sure they were Date, and now get the error "in seq.int(0, to0 - from,by): Wrong sign in 'by' argument)

Comment: @datahappy Could you try with the `dput` data I used (updated now in the post)

Comment: Maybe he can't install packages.@datahappy, does this base approach works for you? `df$ForSale <- lapply(split(df, df[, 1:2], drop = TRUE), function(x) toString(seq(as.Date(x[,3]), as.Date(x[,4]), by  = '1 day')))`

Comment: I have added the str(data) to the OP

Comment: Worked perfectly with the dput you posted.  Have the same sign error in R console with my data

Comment: @datahappy Also, please do post a small example `dput` output that doesn't work.

Comment: @akun It should be there now.  Also, it works on dput.  Trying to find the point where it fails now.  Seems an issue on my end, not with the coding/structure of data

Comment: Found it!  Data entry error in the DT.  On six occasions, someone entered the wrong year, making it look like the Active date was after the Closed date, causing a sign error.  Marking solved.  Thank you so much for your help!